# determine eigenvalues for $L$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

> \begin{align*}
> L\colon P_2(\mathbb R) &\longrightarrow P_2(\mathbb R), \\
> p &\longmapsto X\cdot p'-p'
> \end{align*}

hi, I have problems with this problem it sounds.

In this problem we consider the real vector space $P_2(\mathbb{R})$ of real polynomials $a + bX$, where $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ of degree $\leq 1$
Determine all the eigenvalues for $L$?

normally, my idea for finding the eigenvalues is to find the characteristic polynomial but i cant in this problem how.

usually I have a $2\times2$ or $3\times3$ matrix where I then find it $\det(A-\lambda I)$.

Thanks in advance

Comment: $P_2(\Bbb{R})$ is the space of real polynomials of degree $\leq2$. Then what heve you written "where the polynomial is given by $a+bX$"?

Comment: You edited the question and again wrote mathematical terms in non mathematical mode.

Answer (score 1):

The set $B=\{1,X\}$ is a basis of $P_2(\Bbb R)$. Besides, $L(1)=0$ and $L(X)=X-1$. Therefore, the matrix of $L$ with respect to the basis $B$ is $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}0&-1\\0&1\end{smallmatrix}\right]$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: $P_2(\Bbb{R})$ is set of all real polynomials of degree $\leq 2$. So I hope you need to take the basis $\{1,X,X^2\}$.

Comment: @A.Sharma Then why did the OP write “where the polynomial is given by $a+bX$”?

Comment: Yes, that is his mistake.

Comment: I am not sure about that. I have seen the space of all polynomials in one variable, real coefficients and degree *smaller* than $n$ denoted by $P_n(\Bbb R)$. With this notation $\dim P_n(\Bbb R)=n$.

Comment: I don't know, I everywhere have seen my definition. So please change your answer.

Comment: I shall do it only if the OP changes the question.